# window.scrollTo() continuous click position is incorrect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a simple back to the top function, our company is using ReactJS to develop

Here is my code:

```
Back_Top() {
    window.scrollTo({top: 0})
}
```

```
render() {
    return (
        <a className="fs-1 screen-button" id="Button_Back_Top" style={{ display: "block" }} onClick={() => { this.Back_Top() }}>
            <i className="bi bi-arrow-up-circle-fill"></i>
        </a>
    )
}
```

My approach is to give that `<a>` an onClick event, and use window.scrollTo({top: 0}) directly to achieve it.
But at present it seems that although I can successfully slide to the top of the page, as long as I press it several times, it will slide up a little and then get stuck.
Although you can successfully slide to the top with just one click, it still feels weird, please give me some pointers!

Comment: It's very tough to debug an issue like this without a working example, a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot.

Comment: What do you mean with "it feels weird" ? I don't get whats actually wrong

Comment: I created a sandbox with (a little modified version of) your code and it just works as expected. What am I missing? https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-albattani-ls4y5o?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: https://imgur.com/gHoi3WE

Comment: Like this GIF, you can see